# How come some methods don't require parentheses?

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
num = 1 + 1j
print(num.imag)
```

As opposed to

```
word = "hey"
print(word.islower())
```

One requires parentheses, and the other doesn't. I know in Python when we call functions without parentheses, we get back only a reference to the function, but it doesn't really answer it. So 'imag' returns a reference? because it seems the method does get executed and returns the imag part.

Comment: Attributes and properties do not require parentheses. Functions and methods require parentheses.

Comment: You never call functions without parentheses: the parentheses *are* the call. Any name in Python can refer to any value, and many values are callable. The parentheses are basically the "operator" that invokes a callable value's `__call__` method. (That is, `x(...)` is equivalent to x.__call__(...)`.)

Answer (score 1):

`imag` is not a method. It's simply a number-valued attribute.

`islower` *is* a method. In order to *call* the method, you put parentheses after the name.

Answer (score 0):

`num.imag` is not a function, it's an attribute. To call a function you need the parentheses, or the `__call__` method.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes (e.g. imag) are like variables inside the object so you don't use parentheses to access them.  Methods (e.g. islower()) are like functions inside the object so they do require parentheses to accept zero or more parameters and perform some work.

Objects can also have 'properties' that are special functions that behave like attributes (i.e. no parentheses) but can perform calculation or additional work when they are referenced or assigned.